# Spring Boot LDAP authentication over Tomcat (Pre-Authentication)

Tags: tomcat, authentication, spring-boot, spring-security, ldap

I'm creating a Spring Boot application, which should be accessible only to users in LDAP. This application should be deployed to a Tomcat server (not an embedded server). The configuration for the LDAP is done in Tomcat itself:

```xml
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
        resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm"
        connectionURL="ldap://someldapserver:389"
        userPattern="uid={0},dc=example,dc=com"
        roleBase="dc=example,dc=com"
        roleName="cn"
        roleSearch="(uniqueMember={0})"/>
</Realm>
```

If I try to access the Tomcat Manager, I can authenticate with LDAP credentials, so the connection basically works.

This is my configuration:

```java
@Configuration
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/test").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin().permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout().permitAll()
                .and()
            .csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

I know I could configure the LDAP connection directly in the application (`authenticationManagerBuilder.ldapAuthentication()...`), but this is not what I want.

How can I tell Spring Boot to use the LDAP authentication from Tomcat for the application?

**UPDATE**

It looks like I have to enable [Pre-Authentication](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#preauth). This can be done with `.and().jee().mappableRoles("ROLE_ADMIN")`. This seems to work, but I still can't authenticate: `No pre-authenticated principal found in request`.

Do I have to add something to Tomcats configuration?

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find any suitable solution for this, so I removed Spring Security entirely and added the constraints to a `web.xml`. With the `context.xml` it is possible to set the authentication method (e.g. if you wish to switch to tomcat-users.xml authentication, see example below). Then the authentication over Tomcat works.

web.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app>
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Authentication</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/test/test</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>users</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    </login-config>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>users</role-name>
    </security-role>
</web-app>
```

context.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
</Context>
```